# Direct Mutual funds in India through Demat

Tags: india, mutual-funds

I am aware that Mutual funds are available in India in two flavors, Regular and Direct. Also, I have been using my Demat account to buy units in Mutual fund. However, I find many Direct options are missing while trying to purchase through my Demat account, though Regular option is available.

My queries are 
1. Is it mandatory to provide Direct and Regular options for all Mutual funds in India?
2. Is it mandatory to provide the same in Demat mode as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to provide Direct and Regular options for all Mutual funds in India?

It is mandatory to provide a direct plan going forward. i.e. Mutual Fund can have only direct plan and not regular.

> Is it mandatory to provide the same in Demat mode as well?

Availability for purchase via Demat is optional for the Fund Houses to decide. A fund can list select schemes for purchase via Demat.